# Kettle Parallel running meeting error

Tags: kettle

When i using shell to run multiple kettle transform (Using pan.sh)
meet problem. I using Debug mode to get what caused this error.but finding nothing.

I guess there may not be enough resources, but I am not sure.

1. Using `lsof -p PID` to get Usage of fd is enough
2. Looking for process number and find it enough

But when I ran transformation,  CPU Usage is very high.
But total CPU is lower ,almost of CPU is idle!

Comment: lax Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Two thing you can try - ktr setting -> miscellaneous -> there are three option normal, single-threaded, single threaded for Hadoop.

Try single threaded as your table may do updates which will throw error wen your try multiple.

Also increase the memory based on number of copies you would like to run in parallel.

Choose tick when this answer is right as it may help others.

Thanks,
Sivasakthi.

Comment: I have change it to single threaded.but i can't run more than five trans parallel, how can i about ten trans